# libPods.a not found

Tags: ios, xcode

This has been answered many times, but I couldn't seem to find an answer that worked.

I'm building a cordova app. I added GCM and when I build in Xcode, it doesn't give me any errors. When I build from the command line for cordova, I get `library not found for -lPods-App`. In my project, it shows `libPods-App.a` in red (the name is different as well). When I select it and view the source control on the right, the location is not correct. If I search my computer, none of those libraries in red are found either.

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

How could I fix this? Thanks!

I'm currently working in the .xcworkspace, so that isn't the issue. I al

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this worked.  Here's what I did: but I clicked on the buggy file on the left, and it brought up the window on the right that you see.  There is a little folder icon next to the name of the file, right above the full path.  I clicked that.  It brought up a finder window where I double-clicked libCordova.a to select it.  Then I rebuilt and it worked!